# Pass nested dictionary from views to template django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-views, django-templates

So, I'm new to Django and I'm trying to pass data from my view to a template. I've understood how to pass the classic dictionary but I now need to use a nested dictionary.

For instance, I have a dictionary as below

```
my_dictionary = {0: {'title': 'Beyond the Soul', 'id': '2Uy66My5oKcBEIW7DvVk3V'},
1: {'title': 'The Groove Cartel Selection', 'id': '1pHtICGI68RmWEKnnP5wGr'},
2: {'title':
 'STMPD RCRDS TOP 50', 'id': '1OIzwJTbrOeZTHvUXf5yMg'},
3: {'title': 'House Party by Axwell', 'id': '1tl4L77FJju5zp9bJC83u8'}}
```

From my view I'm returning `return render(request, 'show_playlist.html', my_dictionary )` but If I use `{{ main_playlist[0] }}` it gives *Could not parse the remainder* error

Is there a way to access nested dictionary in templates?

I've tried from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097918/how-do-i-read-a-nested-dictionary-in-a-django-template) bu doesn't show anything

```
{% for key, value in main_playlist.items %}
    <p> {{key}}: {{value.title}} </p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does `{% main_playlist[0] %}` give the same error?

Comment: `return render(request, 'show_playlist.html', {"main_playlist": my_dictionary} )`

Comment: @JacobIRR it returns `Invalid block tag`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a nested dictionary in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097918/how-do-i-read-a-nested-dictionary-in-a-django-template)

Comment: @wjh18 I've literally wrote it doesn't on the question

Comment: @NictheDEV I flagged it as a duplicate question and it automatically posted that. Sorry. That should work you just had the wrong context variable passed in your response as stated by Brian. And it's a better solution than manually accessing the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context data has to be named properly if you want to use `main_playlist` on the template so:

```
return render(request, 'show_playlist.html', {"main_playlist": my_dictionary} )
```